# Webscraping - Tesco Webshop prices - Python requests

Tags: web-scraping, cookies, python-requests

I have been tracking beer webshop prices of Tesco for a while, but this Monday they have implemented something which I am struggling to resolve. I am using requests to get the html content and then scrapy to extract the required data. I have only been passing User-Agent in headers so far, which was enough to get a response, but now no respond.

The only way I could make my script working again is opening the link in browser manually, and copying the entire Cookie from Requests headers into my python script headers next to the User-Agent.

Yet I don't really know how I could generate the required part of this Cookie automatically. The script would be running automatically on a daily basis, but now it requires me to modify the headers cookie part every time.

Is there any way to automate this?

Thank you really much in advance!
Mate

```
import requests
from scrapy import Selector

headers = {
             'Cookie': **'here comes the entire requests cookie string from browser manually'**,
             'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
 }

page_url = ('https://bevasarlas.tesco.hu/groceries/hu-HU/shop/alkohol/sor-cider/all')
html = requests.get(url = page_url, headers = headers, timeout = 10).content

sel = Selector(text = html)
scraped_data = sel.xpath('//li[contains(@class, "product-list--list-item")]')
card = scraped_data[0]
name = card.xpath('.//span[@class="styled__Text-sc-1xbujuz-1 ldbwMG beans-link__text"]/text()').extract()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the `html` from `requests.get` without sending a cookie:

```js
<script>
   var i = 1686331817;
   var j = i + Number("6194" + "69765");
</script>
```

```js
xhr.open("POST", "/_sec/verify?provider=interstitial", false);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
   "bm-verify": "AAQAAAAH/////7F2shgQtGib96HBSdl5...",
   "pow": j
}));
```

What happens is `j` is calculated and sent along with `bm-verify` to the`/_sec/` URL.

This then gives you an authenticated cookie, and the web browser reloads the page.

You can implement these steps manually.

One other thing of note is that the `Referer` header appears to be checked, so you must set it.

```
import re
import requests
from   scrapy import Selector

site = 'https://bevasarlas.tesco.hu'

sec  = site + '/_sec/verify?provider=interstitial'
page = site + '/groceries/hu-HU/shop/alkohol/sor-cider/all'

headers = {
   'User-Agent': (
      'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 ' 
      '(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
   ),
   'Referer': page,
}

r = requests.get(page, headers=headers)

html = r.content

# extract `i`, `j` and `bm-verify`
i = re.search(rb'var i = (\d+)', html)[1]
j = re.search(rb'var j = i [+] Number[(]"(\d+)" [+] "(\d+)"[)]', html)
j = j[1] + j[2]

payload = {
   'bm-verify': re.search(rb'"bm-verify"\s*:\s*"([^"]+)', html)[1].decode(),
   'pow': int(i) + int(j)
}

rr = requests.post(sec, cookies=r.cookies, json=payload, headers=headers)

rrr = requests.get(page, cookies=rr.cookies, headers=headers)

html = rrr.content
sel = Selector(text = html)

scraped_data = sel.xpath('//li[contains(@class, "product-list--list-item")]')
card = scraped_data[0]
name = card.xpath('.//span[@class="styled__Text-sc-1xbujuz-1 ldbwMG beans-link__text"]/text()').extract()

print(name)
```

Output:

```
['Rastinger világos sör 4% 500 ml']
```

You can probably clean up the code by using a Session object and letting that handle the cookies/headers for you.

Comment: Unluckily now getting permission denied... :(

Comment: @MateP Yes not sure what has changed, I've added a new working version.